# Animations in flash to IOS

Tags: ios, flash, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing an application that presents different stories for kids.

These stories are already made ​​in flash. 
My problem is how to add to the storys That app.

Initially one of the approaches was to create an app in Coco2D and make the animations in this language (converting the animations in pictures). However due to possess many animations and sounds, this process is very complicated

Thus, I asked opinions on what approach should I do to solve this problem.
Any opinion will help.

Thanks...

Comment: Does it contain many interactive elements? Otherwise it might be possible to just turn it into a video file

Comment: Yes, it had.. but few... Can I convert my flash to HTML5 and just add that in my IOS App??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the way you will solve the problem, you can try Adore Air which let you use Flash on iOS Apps :
 [An example on how to do this](http://flashsimulations.com/2010/10/25/how-to-create-ios-applications-with-adobe-air/)
If you want to continue with Cocos2D, you can find good tutorials there for your project :
[Good Tutorials to make a project with Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/7001)

If your stories doesn't have any interactive elements, you can try to convert your stories in Flash to Video Files with some softwares (try to enter it in Google).

Comment: The application should allow the user to buy new stories. With the first solution can i realize that?

Comment: Sure. The only difference is that you can play Flash on iOS Apps. 
The only "bad thing" is that you can't open a browser with Flash inside from your application but it is Apple's choice.